# AcquireCredentialsHandle returns SEC_E_SECPKG_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, kerberos, ntlm

When attempting to retrieve the credential handler on Windows 10, I get this error no matter what I provide the function for the security package.  Kerberos is the default on Windows systems so I am attempting to make the following call:

SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY *ident = NULL; // this is filled in with valid credentials
static CredHandle credHandle;

AcquireCredentialsHandle( NULL, "Kerberos", SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, NULL, (void*)ident, NULL, NULL, &credHandle, NULL );

I've verified in my registry that Kerberos is present with other security packages.  It does not matter which package I try to use (Kerberos, SChannel, NTLM, etc), I keep getting the same error.

Comment: You should stick to "Negotiate" as that is technically the default.

Comment: This results in the same error as all the other packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the issue was.  There is a UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion issue with just using a string such as "Negotiate".  In order to resolve this the following must be used in place of a plain string:
(TCHAR*)TEXT("Negotiate")